# Bosh Error Message in Debian server

Tags: php, debian, bots

HI, I have a debian server.
I am using xmpphp library for bot development.
When i create a bot using xmpp file its working fine but when i try to use bosh it generates a fatal error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/testlib/XMPPHP/BOSH.php:75
Stack trace:

0 /var/www/testlib/XMPPHP/BOSH.php(75): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')

1 /var/www/testlib/index.php(14): XMPPHP_BOSH->connect('myserver')

2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/testlib/XMPPHP/BOSH.php on line 75

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but could it be related to this known bug:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42682